# Understanding align-items: baseline

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It makes sense that under `align-items: baseline`, the items on each row whose baselines appear the highest will 'shift down' to meet the lowest baseline.

Why is there no discernible change when I make only item2 `align-self: baseline;`? I can see the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-baselines) but I'm actually struggling to understand it.

```css
html {
    font-family: "Ranchers";
    font-size: 16px;
}

#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;  
}

#flex-container > div:nth-child(1) {
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid black 5px;
    margin: 8px;
    flex-basis: auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
}

#flex-container > div:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid black 10px;
    border-top: solid black 20px;
    margin: 4px;
    align-self: baseline;
}

#flex-container > div:nth-child(3) {
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid black 10px;
    flex-basis: auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<head>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ranchers&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  
 <div id="flex-container">
    <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
    <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2</div>
    <div style="background-color: green;">I am div 3</div>   
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It makes sense that under align-items: baseline, the items on each row whose baselines appear the highest will 'shift down' to meet the lowest baseline.

Using `align-items: baseline` will give you an intuitive result because it will apply baseline alignment to **all** the elements (I insist on all). So its result will be the same as applying `align-self:baseline` to all the elements

```css
html {
  font-family: "Ranchers";
  font-size: 16px;
}

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

#flex-container>div:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 8px;
  flex-basis: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  align-self: baseline; /* here */
}

#flex-container>div:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid black 10px;
  border-top: solid black 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  align-self: baseline; /* here */
}

#flex-container>div:nth-child(3) {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 10px;
  flex-basis: auto;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ranchers&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div id="flex-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">I am div 3</div>
</div>
```

Now, applying baseline to only one element is a different story because the other one will have its default alignment or the one defined by `align-items` (which is `flex-start` in your case). So we start placing the first item following this rule:

> flex-start
>
> The cross-start margin edge of **the flex item is placed flush with the cross-start edge of the line**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)</sup>

Then we place the second one:

> baseline
>
> The flex item participates in baseline alignment: all participating flex items on the line are aligned such that their baselines align, and **the item with the largest distance between its baseline and its cross-start margin edge is placed flush against the cross-start edge of the line**.

So following both rules, both item are placed *flush against the cross-start edge of the line*.

```css
html {
  font-family: "Ranchers";
  font-size: 16px;
}

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

#flex-container>div:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 8px;
  flex-basis: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

#flex-container>div:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid black 10px;
  border-top: solid black 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  align-self: baseline; /* here */
}

#flex-container>div:nth-child(3) {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 10px;
  flex-basis: auto;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ranchers&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div id="flex-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">I am div 3</div>
</div>
```

In other words, applying baseline alignment to one element is useless since it's the only one that will participate to the baseline alignment and it will logically be the one with
*the largest distance between its baseline and its cross-start margin edge* and it will get placed on the top.

You will see a difference in case you have at least two elements with baseline alignment:

```css
html {
  font-family: "Ranchers";
  font-size: 16px;
}

#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

#flex-container>div:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 4px;
  flex-basis: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

#flex-container>div:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid black 10px;
  border-top: solid black 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  align-self: baseline; /* here */
}

#flex-container>div:nth-child(3) {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 10px;
  align-self: baseline; /* here */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ranchers&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div id="flex-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div 2</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">I am div 3</div>
</div>

<div id="flex-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;border-top:0">I am div 2</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;padding-top:50px;">I am div 3</div>
</div>
```

Note how in both cases, the blue div will always be on the top and will never participate in the baseline alignment and only the other two are considered.

Comment: *'the item with the largest distance between its baseline and its cross-start margin edge is placed flush against the cross-start edge of the line.'* - that makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: I also wanted to know what `baseline` would mean when `flex-direction: column`. Does that warrant another question or could it be asked here?

Comment: @tonitone120 it will depend on the writing mode I guess. For english langage, it will probably do nothing but for different text it will. Examples: https://jsfiddle.net/kwdrygLs/